# How to set scaleType for NetworkImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, networkimageview, scaletype

I looked into the source code of `NetworkImageView` at [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/d62a616ebca5bfa4f9ec5517208e13f2d501b69a/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java), it sets image by using `setImageBitmap(bitmap)`. Correct me if I'm wrong, the way to scale a bitmap is using `setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(...))`, and `scaleType` for `NetworkImageView` won't work.

For example, I tried `myNetworkImagView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER)` which doesn't work.

Is there a simple way to scale `myNetworkImageView` such as `setScaleType` other than rewriting the `NetworkImageView` class with `createScaledBitmap(...)`?

Comment: Can you post your layout file, I need to see how you used **NetworkImageView**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio got updated to 1.5.1 and `scaletype` is now working for `NetworkImageView`.